# Realm Notification Firing Multiple Times Consecutively

Tags: swift, realm

*Swift 3.1, Xcode 8.3.3*

I have a Realm notification that gets set up in a View Controller in my app, and after my app launches, it fires 4 times in a row.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
notificationToken = realm.addNotificationBlock { notification, realm in
  print("notif: \(notification)") <-- Logs 4 times in a split second
  self.refreshData()
}
```

Since the `refreshData()` method is what refreshes my UI (which contains a graph that gets drawn), I see a jitter/flicker as each refresh hits.

Is there a way to aggregate those notifications into a single one so I only get a single UI refresh?

Comment: You should start by figuring out what is triggering the notification. Also consider filtering only the relevant notifications so it doesn't call refresh for irrelevant changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you set up a notification block on a Realm instance, you will receive a notification per write transaction. To "aggregate" individual notifications into a single one, you need to merge your separate write transactions into a single one.

For example this piece of code fires two notifications:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(Person(value: ["name":"John"]))
    realm.add(Person(value: ["name":"Chris"]))
}

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(Person(value: ["name":"James"]))
}
```

While this code fires only one:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(Person(value: ["name":"John"]))
    realm.add(Person(value: ["name":"Chris"]))
    realm.add(Person(value: ["name":"James"]))
}
```

Clarification based on @bdash's comment, even though the [docs state that](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-notifications) *"Every time a write transaction involving that Realm is committed, no matter which thread or process the write transaction took place on, the notification handler will be fired..."*, in reality notifications from several write transactions might be merged into a single one based on the time it takes for the notification code to process the write transactions.

Comment: This isn't quite right. A notification may be fired for each write transaction, but Realm will also coalesce changes from multiple transactions into a single notification. It entirely depends on how quickly the changes made during the write transaction are processed by Realm's notification code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I based my answer on what I could get from testing and what the docs state, which is this: "Every time a write transaction involving that Realm is committed, no matter which thread or process the write transaction took place on, the notification handler will be fired:". I guess the docs needs some clarification based on your comment.